# What does Jesus mean in Matthew 25:41-46?

Tags: matthew, gospels, layers-of-meaning, olivet-discourse

I have a question concerning the following passage ([Matthew 25:41-46](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2025)):

> 41 “Then he will say to those on his left, ‘Depart from me, you who
>   are cursed, into the eternal fire prepared for the devil and his
>   angels. 42 For I was hungry and you gave me nothing to eat, I was
>   thirsty and you gave me nothing to drink, 43 I was a stranger and you
>   did not invite me in, I needed clothes and you did not clothe me, I
>   was sick and in prison and you did not look after me.’
>
> 44 “They also will answer, ‘Lord, when did we see you hungry or
>   thirsty or a stranger or needing clothes or sick or in prison, and did
>   not help you?’
>
> 45 “He will reply, ‘Truly I tell you, whatever you did not do for one
>   of the least of these, you did not do for me.’
>
> 46 “Then they will go away to eternal punishment, but the righteous to
>   eternal life.”

How do you have to read this passage?

Does it mean that you have a duty to help other people in general (giving them something to eat, to drink, heal them and so on)? Or does it mean that the people back then only had to help Jesus? Does it mean that you only have to help one person or as many as you are able to? And if you don't do that you will literally go to hell?

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/160/who-are-the-least-of-these-my-brothers-in-matthew-25?rq=1 ?

Comment: Is this a topic for biblical hermeneutics or a question about opinions?

Comment: @Seeker: biblical hermeneutics

Comment: Biblical hermeneutics would focus on grammar of the text . What in the text would decide if believers are being discussed or just unfortunate people in the general population?

Comment: @Seeker: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm trying to understand the principle involved. Your link states that interpretation works up from the text. What material is there for us to work up from?

Comment: @Seeker: Your opinion that there is basically nothing there would also be an interesting answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a conservative Evangelical perspective I suggest that the main and contextual theme of the larger passage from which you excerpted verses 41-46 is judgment. Not just any judgment, however, but the judgment of an all-knowing King who knows the righteous from the unrighteous.

As for the eschatological implications of this passage, I won't dare to speculate. I will suggest, however, that the King is Jesus Christ, described in Matthew 24 and 25 as the "Son of Man" (25:31), and his ability and worthiness to judge are taken for granted both here and elsewhere.

The separation of sheep from goats, as I've already intimated, is Jesus's way of illustrating the judgment process by which he will one day distinguish the righteous from the unrighteous, the true believers from the unbelievers, the ones who are truly God's children through the new birth from the ones who are not.

As for what appear to be criteria for being judged to be righteous (viz., feeding the hungry, giving drink to the thirsty, inviting the stranger in, clothing the naked, taking care of the sick, and visiting the imprisoned), Jesus is not teaching salvation by works.

As has often been said, *the salvation which is by faith alone does not come alone.* With the new birth (or birth from above, or regeneration) comes the God-given ability to demonstrate saving faith ***through*** good works, but ***not the requirement to earn*** salvation through good works.

Even the unrighteous in the current age in which we live perform the sorts of good deeds mentioned by Jesus, and more. They spearhead efforts to eradicate disease, they contribute money to worthwhile causes, and they campaign for reforms which will benefit every segment of society, particularly the downtrodden, the oppressed, and the have-nots.

A common utterance among the rich and famous is "I just feel the need to give back," whether that giving back is to the community in which they grew up or perhaps to a cause with which they identify. Another common expression is "to pay it forward," which suggests that generosity--even anonymous generosity, for example, has a way of becoming contagious. In helping others, people express their gratitude for having been helped themselves.

All these sentiments and good deeds are commendable. What will one day literally separate the sheep from the goats is a matter of motivation. On the one hand, the righteous care for the hungry, the thirsty, the outsider, the naked, the sick, and the imprisoned, and they do these things **as unto the Lord**. Their primary motivation is to please the Lord and not to receive the accolades of the world nor to contribute one whit to the salvation already proffered to them at great cost to their Savior and Lord, the Good Shepherd who gave his life for the sheep (see John 11:10 and 14).

On the other hand, the unrighteous, though they are not necessarily lacking in good deeds, fail to perform those good deeds as unto the Lord. Jesus said,

> Truly I say to you, to the extent that you did not do it to one of the least of these, you did not do it to **Me**’ (Matthew 25:45, my emphasis).

You ask if we "have a duty to help other people in general." Yes. Christians do have a duty to help other people. Clearly, we demonstrate our love for God by loving our neighbor as we love ourselves (see Matthew 22:36-40). That love may be expressed in seemingly small and seemingly insignificant ways (such as a cup of cold water given in Jesus' name--see Matthew 10:42 and Mark 9:41), yet when performed "as unto the Lord," God takes notice and rewards it.

In conclusion, Jesus' words are indeed challenging for both the righteous and unrighteous. For the righteous, they can fail to see Jesus in the person they are called to serve. What is more, they can begin to treat their good deeds as onerous duties rather than joyous acts of service. Worse still, they can become self-congratulatory and proud about what good little Christians they are, rather than recognizing they are but unworthy servants who owe their master a debt which can never be repaid.

For the unrighteous, Jesus' words are the death knell to a works-based salvation, since no amount of good works can merit the gifts of God's forgiveness and eternal life. As with Israel of old, so also with unbelieving Jews and Gentiles today (that is, until they throw themselves upon the mercy of God for the radical cleansing they need),

> All of us have become like one who is unclean, and all our righteous acts are like filthy rags; we all shrivel up like a leaf, and like the wind our sins sweep us away (Isaiah 64:6).

Comment: Thank you for this illuminating answer. You say that salvation is a matter of motivation. I can understand that up to a point (if you try to harm people but coincidentally help them that would still be bad) - but consider this scenario: You grew up as a Hindu and studied the religion sincerely which led you to believe that it is the only true religion (and Jesus is a false prophet of an non-existent God). To be a good Hindu you try to be a good person (care for the hungry, the thirsty, the outsider, the naked, the sick, and the imprisoned) - does that mean that you will go to hell?

Comment: @vonjd:A person does not go to hell for failing to perform good deeds. Nor does a person go to heaven for performing good deeds. The ultimate destiny of a person is determined by belief in Jesus and the efficacy of death to forgive sins.. The saying "There is something to believe and someone to receive" is quite accurate, biblically. The failure to believe in Jesus is what condemns a person. Moreover, the Bible teaches that every person is condemned by default for NOT believing in Jesus' death and resurrection.

Comment: @vonjd: Belief in Jesus, which is often (but not always) accompanied by good works befitting a child of God, is what saves a person. The thief on the cross who was crucified along with Jesus had no opportunity to engage in good works, and yet Jesus promised him eternal life in heaven for simply believing that Jesus was his Savior and Lord. Again, our ultimate destiny--heaven or hell--is a matter of belief (or the failure to believe) in Jesus and NOT a matter of good works, regardless of how many or how few good works we perform. Salvation follows belief and good deeds follow belief. Don

Comment: Ok, if your interpretation is correct it sounds more like an evil dictator using mind control to send people to his eternal concentration camp than a good God. Just saying. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @rhetorician "Belief in Jesus, which is often (but not always) accompanied by good works befitting a child of God, is what saves a person" No, Jesus specifically says those who "do not bear fruit" in Him  or those who "do not remain in Me," will be "cut off" and "thrown into the fire and burnt", i.e. sent to Hell. Just like the uselss servent who didn't use the talents (grace) of his master (God). And like His teaching here in the question is specifically teaching.

Comment: Can't agree with you, @SolaGratia; wouldn't be prudent. True enough, true believers can be guided by the fruit or lack thereof when discerning who the unbelievers might be. Judging by fruit, however, is an inexact science, and ultimately only GOD knows those who are his (2 Timothy 2:19), not we. As has been said, "The salvation which comes by faith alone does not come alone." The ability to work out our own salvation is available to every true believer. Even then, however, God works in us to will and to do his good will. Each believer has a unique spiritual growth chart.

Comment: The thief on the cross next to Jesus who asked Jesus to remember him when he came into his kingdom had no chance to grow spiritually, yet Jesus granted him eternal life. One may argue that the repentant thief is "an exception to the rule." To that I say, well, yes he is, but how do you explain it? By works of the Law (or just simply "works") is no one justified, otherwise there would be room in heaven for bragging. Will some saints be given a greater reward in heaven? Yes, but the bema (2 Cor 5:10), where the saints' works will be judged & rewarded,  is NOT the Great White Throne judgment

Comment: (Rev 20:11 ff.), where people's eternal destiny will be determined and made final. The repentant thief on the cross had, I believe, his name written in the Lamb's Book of Life the very moment he repented and believed. I'll concede that not everyone who believes, does so in a moment in time, as did the thief. Some folks become true believers gradually, as the Spirit and the Word do their mysterious work in their hearts. Nevertheless, the entry into God's kingdom is by grace alone through faith alone. I believe that in the final analysis, we're all just unprofitable servants in God's debt.

Comment: We can't debate salvation in a coment thread, as you know. But summarily: Jesus doesn't say 'cut off occasions of sin because it becomes a Christian.' He specifically said it's necessarily if we are to avoid Hell.

Comment: @SolaGratia: You're right about debating in a comment thread. You have my email address (in my bio page). Drop me a line sometime. I'd enjoy discussing these things with you. Don

Comment: @rhetorician The meaning you put in the word "works" is misleading. Paul means the "works of the Law", but with Christ working in one's heart through faith, how one can help not doing Christ's, the eternally and unstoppably working God's works and remain a Christian?! And what are Christ-God's infinite and unstoppable works? Love, compassion, helping the needful etc. unless we freely co-act with Christ working in us, our faith is dead. Had the right robber slackened and not co-worked with his divinely-inspired indignation rebuking his friend, no unsaid and un-acted faith could have saved him!

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili: You are dangerously close to saying we can somehow add to Christ's once-and-for-all work of redemption which he accomplished through his cross death. To even suggest that Christ's shed blood is somehow insufficient to purchase our salvation, that we somehow need to contribute to the salvation which he bled and died to acquire for us is a slap in our Savior's face. Perhaps you are confusing the fruit of salvation ("love, compassion, helping the needful," as you put it) with the prerequisite of repentance. Repentance is NOT a work; rather, it accompanies saving faith.

Comment: The repentant thief on the cross was in no way saved by his rebuke of the unrepentant malefactor. His rebuke was simply an indication that he possessed saving faith. Faith alone saves. Interestingly, however, the faith that saves is never alone. Now THAT is what James the brother of our Lord was saying in the letter which bears his name.

Comment: @rhetorician If I am told that Bach is a great composer and have a glimpse of this by listening a piece, I will certainly believe in it,  but unless I co-act with this inviting initial belief, start listening Bach and come gradually to my own understanding of his greatness, my faith that he is great will remain sterile and dead, parrot-like at best, which is another word for "dead". Similarly, so many Jews believed that Jesus was the Messiah, but due to various reasons did not co-act with this belief and fell out, as did, e.g. Judas, who even acted miracles in the name of Christ at some time.

Answer (score 1):

Scripture - both Old Testament and New - is quite clear that one will be judged according to their works:

> Psalm 62:12 (KJV)
>
> *For thou renderest to every man according to his work*
>
> Job 34:11 (KJV)
>
> *For the work of a man shall he render unto him, And cause every man to find according to his ways.*<sup>1</sup>
>
> Romans 2:5-6 (KJV)
>
> *But after thy hardness and impenitent heart treasurest up unto thyself wrath against the day of wrath and revelation of the righteous judgment of God; Who will render to every man according to his deeds<sup>2</sup>*
>
> Revelation 20:12 (KJV)
>
> *And I saw the dead, small and great, stand before God; and the books were opened: and another book was opened, which is the book of life: and the dead were judged out of those things which were written in the books, according to their works.*
>
> Revelation 22:12 (KJV)
>
> *And, behold, I come quickly; and my reward is with me, to give every man according as his work shall be.*
>
> James 2:14 (KJV)
>
> *What doth it profit, my brethren, though a man say he hath faith, and have not works? Can faith save him?*

The passage on the final judgment (Matthew 25:31-46) deals with the work of almsgiving in particular, which is also addressed in the Old Testament:

> Proverbs 15:27 LXX (Brenton)
>
> *By alms and faithful dealings sins are purged away*
>
> Tobit 12:9 (KJV)
>
> *For alms doth deliver from death, and shall purge away all sin. Those that exercise alms and righteousness shall be filled with life*
>
> Sirach 3:30 (KJV)
>
> *Water will quench a flaming fire; and alms maketh an atonement for sins*

In the teaching, Jesus refers to *the least of these My brethren* (τῶν ἀδελφῶν μου τῶν ἐλαχίστων).  Some have inferred this to mean His own disciples, but more likely He is referring to the poor in general.  This would be consistent with the parable of the ten talents just prior (v.14-30).  One commentary explains:

> By "the least brethren" He means either His own disciples or, simply, all the poor.  For every poor man is Christ's brother for the very reason that Christ, too, spent His life in poverty.  See also God's righteousness, how He acclaims the saints; and see the good disposition of their mind, how they deny, with befitting modesty, that they have cared for Him.  But the Lord accepts as for Himself the things that were done for the poor.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>LXX: *Yea, he renders to a man accordingly as each of them does, and in a man’s path he will find him* (Brenton)</sup>
<sup>2.</sup> <sup>Gr. ἔργα (*erga*) - "works"</sup>
<sup>3.</sup> <sup>Theophylact of Ohrid, *Explanation of the Holy Gospel According to St. Matthew* (tr. from the Greek; Chrysostom Press, 1992), p.219.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

That’s right. Help as much as you can. I believe it extends to supporting politicians that also support the work helping those that need help, including feeding the poor, helping immigrants get out of dangerous situations, supporting special education, adequate healthcare, special olympics. To support those that believe that in cutting taxes to benefit themselves at the detriment of the poor and needy are hypocritical and not following the true path.

Answer (score 0):

We are always told to walk in the spirit after receiving the spirit of God,and it is the enablement of the spirit of Gid that leads us to live a life that is in tandem with Gods GOAL of we being perfect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In the Gospels, the King has arrived and many passages are pertinent to Israel and the fulfillment of prophecy and the coming kingdom. The sermon on the mount is point in fact.  The meek shall inherit the earth???  Not in this (church) age where wars and rumors of wars will continue until Christ returns. Consider the verse regarding the millennium where it states "as it was in the days of Noah so will it be in the coming of the son of man", where only regenerate mankind remains after the flood (Noah and his family) and unbelievers are removed. The context here is similar; believers will be going into the kingdom (millenium) and unbelievers removed.

Comment: Jesus makes no distinction in Matthew 25:41-46 between believers and unbelievers.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! Please [take the tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site functions. Your answer hasn't addressed the question that was asked. Please edit your answer to do so, or delete it and start again.

Answer (score -1):

If you see a needing person and you are able to help him, you do not ask whether he is a Christian or not, you just help: a physician heals not according to religious denomination of anybody, but according to the need of the patient. We all are patients of God - Christians, Muslims, atheists, agnostics, Rastafarians etc. - and should treat each other as co-patients.

Will not it be evil if my atheist neighbours need my help more than my Christian neighbours, and I close my heart's vents of mercy for the first and open for the second because of the religious affinity? Will not then Christ, whose patients also those atheists are, say to me - "I was thirsty and you gave me not water!" Will I dare to answer Him boldly: "They were atheists, a th e i s t s, who denied Your existence, how can I be guilty in not helping them? You are bewildering me!" Then also the sun should be ordered to shed light only and exclusively upon Christians (of which denomination?), but if it is stupid to suppose that one can govern sun's rays according to one's religious doctrines, how much more stupid is to think that the uncreated Sun of Righteousness, God's co-eternal Son would shed light of His mercy qualifiedly and according to puny ideas hatched in 20 centimetre-long brains of humans?

So, if the Sun of Righteousness does not distinguish between His creations and His patients, and if He wants us to become His agents and His rays, so neither we should be puny distinguishers, but be infinite undistinguishers, as He is. Thus, the Gospels have a wonderful, divinely devised circular-argument logic as to whom one is obliged to and in what action Christ is pleased: Whom to help? Your neighbour! Who is your neighbour? Anybody, whom you help (Luke 10:36-37).

Answer (score -1):

If you do not do good works then you obviously do not believe in Jesus. Gods grace is necessary for salvation. We earn grace by feeding the poor etc. If we are truly saved by grace alone. Then we don't need the 10 commandments or the bible.

Comment: You said: “ If we are truly saved by grace alone. Then we don't need the 10 commandments or the bible.”. Where then do you get your teaching or truth that we are “truly saved by grace alone”?

Answer (score -1):

Based on only the text being studied, the conclusion can go either way. The brothers are believers, or they are the unfortunates seen amongst all humanity.

In my opinion, the answer must not be based on an atomistic view, studying only the text offered, but be holistic, must consider the whole tenor of the Scriptures.

All acts can be either :

For God or against God

Serve God or serve mammon

Be selfless or be selfish

Gather or scatter

In fact, all the first mentioned are equivalents, can be interchanged amongst themselves, as can the terms in the  group of the last mentioned.

I have visited countries where the rulers put their political opponents in prison. Obviously, those who visited them were in danger of taking on the same persecution. It is no coincidence, then, that Christ viewed the helping of his brothers to mean a great service to His cause.

This view is also mentioned in the related posts linked.